# What power is stored in Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

There seems to be a number of discrepancies in the power of Mjolnir in the MCU.

In *Thor* Odin places the power of Thor into his hammer Mjolnir proclaiming:

> he who wields the hammer, if he be worthy will have the power of Thor.

At the climax of the film we see Thor regain his powers and armour when he sacrifices himself for the town.

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron* this is reaffirmed when the Avengers try to lift the hammer with only Cap getting close.

In *Thor: Ragnarok* Mjolnir is destroyed and Thor then discovers the powers where inside him all along.

But in *Avengers: Endgame*

> Captain America wields Mjolnir gaining the power of Thor.

However, we saw in *Thor: Ragnarok* that the hammer has no real power of its own, the power was inside Thor all along. In addition Mjolnir being destroyed doesn't affect Thor's strength and when he gets Stormbreaker he becomes more powerful suggesting that Stormbreaker also gives the power of Thor to the wielder.

So does Mjolnir give additional powers and allow the bearer to have the powers of Thor, or is it just a magic hammer that has special powers all of its own?

Comment: _"In Avengers: Age of Ultron this is reaffirmed when the Avengers try to lift the hammer with only Cap getting close."_ It was confirmed that Cap was worth and could lift Mjolnir here but decided not to.

Comment: As Odin says in *Ragnarok*, Mjolnir helps Thor focus his power. Turns out it can help other worthy people focus Thor's power too.